# Deploying artifacts to nexus failed because of super-pom

Tags: maven, deployment, ant, nexus

I'm trying to deploy artifacts in nexus using ant task. It reads pom.xml from the workspace during deploy. I had not mentioned super-pom anywhere but still it tries to deploy that. Anybody knows what is the reason of this? and how can I avoid this?

**Error Log :**

```
[artifact:deploy] Deploying to http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX/nexus/content/repositories/XXXXXXXXX/
[artifact:deploy] Uploading: org/apache/maven/super-pom/2.0/super-pom-2.0.jar to repository remote at 

http://XX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX/nexus/content/repositories/XXXXXXXXX/
[artifact:deploy] Transferring 976K from remote
[artifact:deploy] Uploaded 976K
[artifact:deploy] [INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from remote
[artifact:deploy] [INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact org.apache.maven:super-pom'
[artifact:deploy] [INFO] Uploading project information for super-pom 2.0
[artifact:deploy] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
[artifact:deploy]  Diagnosis:
[artifact:deploy] 
[artifact:deploy] Error deploying artifact 'org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar': Error installing artifact's metadata: Error while deploying metadata: Specified source file does not exist: /home/XXXXXXXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/super-pom/2.0/super-pom-2.0.pom
[artifact:deploy] /home/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/super-pom/2.0/super-pom-2.0.pom (No such file or directory)
BUILD FAILED
/home/xxxxxx/.jenkins/jobs/XXXXXXXXX/workspace/build.xml:44: Error deploying artifact 'org.apache.maven:super-pom:jar': Error installing artifact's metadata: Error while deploying metadata: Specified source file does not exist: /home/XXXXXXX/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/super-pom/2.0/super-pom-2.0.pom
```

Code in my build.xml

```
<target name="deploy">                          
    <artifact:deploy file="${destination}/${serviceName}.ear">
        <remoteRepository url="${nexus-staging-repository-url}">
            <authentication username="${nexus.username}" password="${nexus.password}" />
        </remoteRepository>
        <pom refid="mypom"/>
        <attach file="${destination}/${serviceName}_1.xml" type="xml"/>
        <attach file="${destination}/${serviceName}.cfg" type="cfg"/>
    </artifact:deploy>
</target>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>dbs</groupId>
<artifactId>cipoc</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
<name>cipoc</name>
</project>
```

Comment: Why are you using an ant task to deploy to nexus? You can use the defautls like maven-deploy-plugin to deploy artifact to nexus. The super-pom must be mentioned in your pom or in one of it's parents.

Comment: I'm using same maven-deploy-plugin. Please see my code in question. :)

Comment: It would be helpful having the full pom file and which maven version you are using furthermore the plugin versions you are using and apart from that i don't understand why you are using ant task. You can attach files via build-helper-maven-plugin. Unfortunately the code only shoes me that you are trying to deploy artifacts via ant/antrun which does not make sense to me

Comment: The super-pom you have must be somewhere in your artifacts (pom's being used) cause it does not exist in Maven Central.

Comment: Ohh sorry! I misunderstood previously. The reason I'm not using maven-deploy-plugin is I want to deploy many other files to nexus like xml, props, cfg etc. Also, my project is not Maven based which means it generates artifacts using Ant.

Comment: First i would suggest to change your project to a maven project where you can simply add supplemental artifacts as i mentioned already. Furthermore the deployment of the usual artifacts like ear files will be done out of the box.

Comment: Thanks dude! I think that will work.. :)
I'll use this approach and let you know.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Ear deployment happens nicely. Now, how can I deploy folder (i.e. all files in folder)?

Comment: You can't deploy a folder. A Maven repository contains artifacts no folders. You can zip those folders via maven-assembly-plugin for example...